# Smart One Page Checkout Breaks Credit Card Processor

Tags: magento2.3, authorize.net

I'm using AheadWorks Smart One Page Checkout for Magento 2 and for some reason it completely breaks my authorize.net credit card processing.

I receive this error in the payment.log

```
'response' => '{"transactionResponse":{"SupplementalDataQualificationIndicator":0},"messages":{"resultCode":"Error","message":[{"code":"E00076","text":"dataDescriptor contains invalid value."},{"code":"E00076","text":"dataValue contains invalid value."}]}}',
```

That's an authorize.net error code, but the only detail they give on their error code lists is that an invalid value was given. When you're actually checking out, the only error displayed is a regular "Credit Card Declined" message.  The credit card section also has a display error that may or may not be related to the error code.

Here is a screenshot with the display error marked with an arrow.

[image]

I cannot tell whether this display error is causing the invalid submission or not. Authorize.net credit card processing works perfectly fine the second I disable One Page checkout, and the error occurs even on a brand new clean Magento 2.3.1 installation.

I've tried all I can think of and am looking for any ideas on potential solutions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error will be displayed?

Comment: On the actual page the only thing that is displayed is a regular "Credit Card Declined" message.

Comment: @Sabiancym: I am also facing this same issue, were you able to get over it ?

Comment: @NarendraVyas I am facing same issue, did you get any solution related to this ?
I am using Magento 2.3.1

Comment: Same issue faced, did you find any solution? Please share your comment.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the following piece of code:

```
if (self._getMethodRenderComponent().index == 'authorizenet_acceptjs') {
                self._getMethodRenderComponent().beforePlaceOrder();
              }else
```

between:

```
this._beforeAction().done(function () {
```

and:

```
self._getMethodRenderComponent().placeOrder(data, event);
```

in:
app/code/Aheadworks/OneStepCheckout/view/frontend/web/js/view/actions-toolbar/renderer/default.js